# Unable to find Xpath for author in the link

Tags: xpath

For the link
http://www.gptoday.com/full_story/view/481779/
I am unable to identify the Xpath for the author - Andrew Benson

Ok i am using CHrome Developers tool to locate the element and then the Xpath CHecker in Chrome to validate it back.
My guess was //div[@class='entry-info']//a should work
OR //div[@class='entry-info']/div/a should have worked.

Comment: Can you please improve your question with more detailed information? For instance, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I Just did :)  I am wondering why the xpath is not working for this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find an XPath selector for it is because it doesn't exist on that page. That page wraps the BBC article in an `iframe` (probably violating the TOS of BBC.com). You'd have to follow the URL to the BBC.com article in the `iframe`. Once you have retrieved the proper URL (in this case http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/formula1/26647993), you can use the following XPath:

```
substring-after(//*[@class='article']//*[@itemprop='name'],'By ')
```

which returns `Andrew Benson` as you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. How did you get the URL http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/formula1/26647993?

Comment: View source on the gptoday.com site, and you see the <iframe> with the URL to the BBC site.